# Is the armorist capstone ability useless on a blaster archetype?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, class, archetype, spheres-of-power

The [armorist](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/armorist) level 20 ability:

> **Infinite Arsenal (Su)**
>
> At level 20, you no longer need to spend a spell point to summon equipment.

But on the [blaster](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/blaster) archetype, summon equipment is replaced:

> **Destruction:** [...]
>
> This replaces the summon equipment class feature.

However, blaster does not replace IA. I thought the capstone was affecting bound equipment, but bound equipment does not cost a SP to summon from lv 1 anyway.

> Table: The Armorist
>
> 1st   [...]   Bound equipment, casting, spell pool, summon equipment [...]
>
> [...] Bound equipment is summoned and treated just like summoned equipment, except it does not cost a spell point to summon [...]

Am I missing something obvious on the archetype, or the lv 20 ability is really useless?

Answer (score 1):

You would be absolutely correct in the assumption that **it is truly useless for the Blaster archetype**.  The 20th level armorist ability Infinite Arsenal simply does not apply because you relinquish the Summon Equipment class feature that Infinite Arsenal is based on and instead take the archetype features.

It is the definition of the downside of an archetype; you focus solely on one aspect of the class to specialize in which is often modified in some way, and you drop some other things in exchange for that power.  In this case, you get a ranged ray weapon that you can summon for free as a bound weapon and get specialized Arsenal Tricks for it at the cost of summoning literally anything else.

Comment: One might consider it bad design by the game studio that brought that archetype.

Comment: Could be.   There's any number of reasons why this archetype is so specific with its rules.  I really do feel like it takes away from what the armorist was supposed to be, but that's just my opinion.  If nothing else, it certainly does simplify the class down.